# Titanium: Window transitions not working on Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to add window transitions to when opening and closing a window in Android.

Creating transistions for Windows is described in the docs here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window

foo.js has the following tss file:

```
"#win": {
    theme: "Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar",
    fullscreen: false, // To make it heavy-weight (although this should not be needed for > v3.2.0)
}
```

I have tried the following methods:

**Method 1**

```
Alloy.createController('foo')
    .getView().open({
        activityEnterAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_in,
        activityExitAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_out
    });
```

The above enter animation works as expected. However, the fade out does not work.

**Method 2**

```
Alloy.createController('foo')
    .getView().open({
        activityEnterAnimation: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_FADE_IN,
        activityExitAnimation: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_FADE_OUT
    });
```

Neither fade in or fade out worked

**Method 3**

```
"#win[platform=android]": {
    activityEnterAnimation: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_FADE_IN,
    activityExitAnimation: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_FADE_OUT,

    // OR
    // activityEnterAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_in,
    // activityExitAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_out,
}
```

Neither fade in or fade out worked for either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

**activity*Transitions**

There is currently no way to use the `activity*Transitions` without a sharedElement. There is an open ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20507 that shows a fix (needs to be adjusted for the first window or add `animated:false` when opening the first window if you use the fix).

**activity*Animation**

The `activity*Animation` animations are working like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#f00'
});

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "open"
});

win.add(btn);

var btn2 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "close"
});

win2.add(btn2);

btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    win2.close({
        activityExitAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_out
    });
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    win2.open({
        activityEnterAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_in,
        activityExitAnimation: Ti.Android.R.anim.fade_out
    });
});

win.open();
```

Tested with 6.1.2.GA and 6.2.2.GA

**Workaround for activity*Transitions**

The `activity*Transitions` are working like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    activityEnterTransition: Titanium.UI.Android.SLIDE_RIGHT,
    activityExitTransition: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_EXPLODE
});

var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#f00',
   activityEnterTransition: Titanium.UI.Android.SLIDE_RIGHT,
    activityExitTransition: Titanium.UI.Android.TRANSITION_EXPLODE
});
// Create label in window A with a unique transitionName.
var titleInWinA = new Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Top 10 pics from Mars!',
    left: 70,
    top: 6,
    width: 200,
    height: 30,
    transitionName: 'title',
    color: "#000"
});
win.add(titleInWinA);

var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "open"
});
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    win2.addSharedElement(titleInWinA, "title");
    win2.open();
});
win.add(btn);
win.open();
var titleInWinB = new Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Top 10 pics from Mars!',
    left: 50,
    top: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 30,
    transitionName: 'title',
    color: "#000"
});
win2.add(titleInWinB);
```

Keep in mind that they are `creation only` properties of the window and aren't used as parameters for `window.open()` like the `activity*Animation`

Answer (score 1):

Yahya Uddin

window transitions is not works in android , if you want to animate the windows then you have to use animation with settimeout. and its custom.

Comment: What do you it's not working? Is it a bug? Haas it been reported?